# Datatables Angular JS set page length

Tags: angularjs, datatable

How do I set the page length in an AngularJS Datatable?
Right off the bat, people are going to want to say this ...

```
$('#example'String).dataTable( {

  "pageLength"String: 50

} );
```

This answer will not work for me because I am not defining my datatable like that. 
I am creating it like this with ng...

```
<table datatable="ng" id="orderTable" dt-options="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ng-init="initTableData()">
```

Then I am defining the `<thead>` and `<tbody>`, then within the `<tbody>` I am defining the `<tr>` with `ng-repeat` like so...

```
 <tr ng-repeat="order in orders track by $index">
```

So the table is getting created on the fly with AngularJS and HTML. With this design, how can I change the `pageLength` without having to switch to the previously mentioned pattern at the top of my question?

Answer (score 4):

The default length Menu is 25, 50, 100...

You can set the initial display length as below.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(25);
```

In case you want to define your own length Menu, do as below with initial display length of table as 5.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(5).withOption('lengthMenu', [[5, 10, 15, 20, 25,-1],[5,10,15,20,25,"All"]]);
```

From [angular-datatables API info](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/api), it is evident under **DTOptionsBuilder** that `withDisplayLength(iDisplayLength)` is used to set the number of items per page to display where **iDisplayLength** is your preferred size.

Comment: some explanation of solution and formatting will help all.

Comment: Edited the answer!